# Why is it that you can change the PDF/PMF argument for related random variables to produce new PDF/PMF equality statements?

Tags: probability-distributions

For random variables

$$N_1 \sim P(\lambda_1)$$ $$N_2 \sim P(\lambda_2)$$ $$N \sim P(\lambda)$$ where $N=N_1+N_2$ and $N_1$, $N_2$ are independent.

Why is the following statement true?

$$P(N_1=n_1)=P(N=n,N_2=n-n_1)$$

In other words, why is the $probability$ of $(N_1 = n_1)$ equal to the $joint$ $probability$ of $(N=n \cap N_2=n-n_1)$. I know that algebraically they are true when treating them as 'normal' variables.

Comment: This is wrong, actually, $$P(N_1=n_1)=\sum_{n=n_1}^\infty P(N=n,N_2=n-n_1).$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not true.

We indeed have:
$$
\big \{\omega : (N(\omega) = n) \wedge (N_2(\omega) = n - n_1)\big\} = \big \{\omega : (N_1(\omega) = n_1) \wedge (N_2(\omega) = n - n_1) \big\},
$$
because:
$$
\Big( (N(\omega)=n) \wedge (N_2(\omega) = n - n_1) \Big) \Rightarrow
\Big( (N_1(\omega)=n_1) \wedge (N_2(\omega) = n - n_1) \Big),
$$
and because:
$$
\Big( (N_1(\omega)=n_1) \wedge (N_2(\omega) = n - n_1) \Big) \Rightarrow
\Big( (N(\omega)=n) \wedge (N_2(\omega) = n - n_1) \Big).
$$

We thus have:
$$
\mathbb{P}[(N=n)\wedge(N_2=n-n_1)] = \mathbb{P}[(N_1=n_1)\wedge(N_2=n-n_1)],
$$
and then:
$$
\mathbb{P}[(N=n)\wedge(N_2=n-n_1)] = \mathbb{P}[N_1=n_1]\mathbb{P}[N_2=n-n_1],
$$
since $N_1$ and $N_2$ are independent.