# How to show that a poisson distribution for a random variable becomes a binomial distribution, given the following conditional probability condition?

Tags: poisson-distribution, binomial-distribution

For Poisson random variables $$N_1 \sim P(\lambda_1)$$ $$N_2 \sim P(\lambda_2)$$ $$N \sim P(\lambda)$$ where $N=N_1+N_2$ and $N_1$, $N_2$ are independent, how to show that $P(N_1=n_1)$ or $P(N_2=n_2)$ follows a binomial distribution, for a given value of $N$?

Comment: What is $\mu$? Cause usually Poison distribution has one parameter $\lambda$.

Comment: It was a mistake, I'll edit it. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $N_1 \sim \mathcal{P}(\lambda_1)$ and $N_2 \sim \mathcal{P}(\lambda_2)$. Assume that $N_1$ and $N_2$ are independent. Let $N = N_1 + N_2$ and  $\lambda = \lambda_1 + \lambda_2$. [We then have](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loi_de_Poisson#Stabilit.C3.A9_de_la_loi_de_Poisson_par_la_somme) $N = \mathcal{P}(\lambda)$.

From [this page](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1727409/why-is-it-that-you-can-change-the-pdf-pmf-argument-for-related-random-variables/1727431#1727431), we can then write:
$$
\mathbb{P}[(N=n) \wedge (N_2 = n - n_1)] = \mathbb{P}[N_1 = n_1]\,\mathbb{P}[N_2 = n - n_1],
$$
which implies:
$$
\mathbb{P}[N_2 = n - n_1\,\vert\,N=n]\,\mathbb{P}[N=n] = \mathbb{P}[N_1 = n_1]\,\mathbb{P}[N_2 = n - n_1].
$$
We then have:
$$
\mathbb{P}[N_2 = n - n_1\,\vert\,N=n] = \frac{\mathbb{P}[N_1 = n_1]\,\mathbb{P}[N_2 = n - n_1]}{\mathbb{P}[N=n]}
= \frac{ \frac{\lambda_1^{n_1} e^{-\lambda_1}}{n_1!} \frac{\lambda_2^{n - n_1} e^{-\lambda_2}}{(n - n_1)!}}{\frac{\lambda^{n} e^{-\lambda}}{n!}}
$$
$$
= \frac{n!}{n_1! (n - n_1)!} \frac{\lambda_1^{n_1}}{\lambda^{n_1}}
\frac{\lambda_2^{n - n_1}}{\lambda^{n - n_1}} \frac{e^{-\lambda_1}e^{-\lambda_2}}{e^{-\lambda}}.
$$
Since $\lambda_1 + \lambda_2 = \lambda$, we finally find:
$$
\mathbb{P}[N_2 = n - n_1\,\vert\,N=n] = \left( \begin{array}{c} n \\ n_1 \end{array} \right) \left( \frac{\lambda_1}{\lambda} \right)^{n_1} \left(1 - \frac{\lambda_1}{\lambda} \right)^{n - n_1}.
$$

Comment: @kenfunds And now the real mystery is *what was escaping you from all this*.

Comment: Why is $\lambda = \lambda_1 + \lambda_2$ assumed but not true?

Comment: I need this assumption to obtain the final result. I do not check whether it is true.

Comment: I modified my answer. I really need to have $\lambda = \lambda_1 + \lambda_2$, but, using this equation, I can now obtain $N \sim \mathcal{P}(\lambda)$ without assuming it. See also [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution#Related_distributions).

Comment: What is the difference between a logical connective and intersection symbol?

Comment: I use the following notations: $\mathbb{P}[A \wedge B]$ or $\mathbb{P}[\{\omega \in \Omega,\,A(\omega)\} \cap \{\omega \in \Omega,\, B(\omega)\}]$. However, if you write $\mathbb{P}[A \cap B]$, it does not matter and it has the same meaning as the previous expressions.